# Editing/Typing in the post/page editor is very slow in text mode

Tags: wordpress, performance, editor

I am having default theme (twenty sixteen) running over wp version 4.5.2. I've no plugins in active state (all deactivated). Having many pages created with long contents (about 500+ pages).

One of the page is having 18,997 words (http://surgemedia.staging.wpengine.com/6-mo-after-gastric-sleeve-warnings-successes). Please do not mind about the formatting since it is copied from live site to this staging site. When I try to edit content in this page in text mode, it is very very slow. I am not able to figure out what's the reason since the content does not have any images or external content.

Please help!

Thank you, Naresh

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will drastically slow down the WP Editor on my computer is to have the Chrome inspector open at the same time.  The inspector can be open on ANY Chrome window or tab and it will affect the WP editor in any of the others.  Hopefully the word will get out and either the WP or Google team will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but have you tried:

- Checking your website speed (for example with: https://tools.pingdom.com/)
- Checking your own network speed
- Disabling browser add-ons / extentions
- Disabling the browsers spelling checker in the text editor
- Using multiple browsers to see if the problem persists

(In case all of the above doesn't work and you haven't encountered a problem like this before):

- Prepare a clean installation of WordPress with a standard theme and copy paste your text into it, in case the current installation is corrupted. Try this on localhost before setting it live, in case the hosting-provider is the cause of the problem.